# How can I use Ruby to find all the weeks in a rolling year?

Tags: ruby

How can I use Ruby to find the date of the Monday of every week in a rolling year that ends on the last Monday before the current date, then create a hash where every key is the date of week and every value is 0?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "a hash where every key is the date of week and every value is 0". Why not just have a hash that always returns `0` for any key?

Comment: Because some of the values will be overwritten with other values but the ones that will not get overwritten need to have 0 as their values.

Comment: The question was unclear to sawa, the Tin Man, fabian, Unheilig, medhi lofti. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question.

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today
prev_monday = today - ((today.wday <= 1) ? today.wday + 6 : today.wday - 1)
  #<Date: 2014-07-28 ((2456867j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I've assumed that if today is Monday (as it is), you want the date a week ago today (not today's date, but if today's date were desired, just change `(today.wday <= 1)` to `(today.wday.zero?)`).

Every rolling year that ends on a Monday will have 53 Mondays. Therefore, a hash with keys for those Mondays would be as follows:

```
52.downto(0).map { |i| [prev_monday - i*7, 0] }.to_h
  #=> {#<Date: 2013-07-29 ((2456503j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0,
  #    #<Date: 2013-08-05 ((2456510j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0,
  ...
  #    #<Date: 2014-07-28 ((2456867j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'
```

Create an empty hash:

```
hash = {}
```

Figure out the days to the previous Monday:

```
days_to_previous_monday = Date.today.wday - 1
days_to_previous_monday = 6 if days_to_previous_monday < 0
```

Get last Monday:

```
date = Date.today - days_to_previous_monday
```

Build a hash of 53 Mondays:

```
53.times { hash[date] = 0; date -= 7 }
```

Sort the hash in ascending date order:

```
hash.sort.to_h
```

EDITED - included Cary Swoveland's corrections and suggestions..(twice!)

Comment: Nice way to build the hash, Steve. I believe a rolling year ending on a Monday has 53 Mondays, however. Also, you could drop `hash[date] = 0` and write `53.times { hash[date] = 0; date -= 7 }`. There may be no need to sort the hash, but if you do, I think you need `hash.sort.to_h`, as `hash.keys.sort` just sorts an array of its keys.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok, thanks, think I got it right this time. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date' #gem install activesupport

today = Date.today
p today  #=>Mon, 04 Aug 2014

prev_day = today.days_ago(1)
p prev_day #=>Sun, 03 Aug 2014

prev_monday = prev_day.beginning_of_week(:monday)  
p prev_monday  #=> Mon, 28 Jul 2014
p prev_monday.prev_week  #=>Mon, 21 Jul 2014
```

So you can do this:

```
prev_monday = today.beginning_of_week(:monday)  #If today is Monday, then returns today.

52.downto(0).each do |i|
  p prev_monday.weeks_ago(i)
end

--output:--
Mon, 05 Aug 2013
Mon, 12 Aug 2013
Mon, 19 Aug 2013
...
...
...
Mon, 21 Jul 2014
Mon, 28 Jul 2014
Mon, 04 Aug 2014
```

The hash can be constructed like this:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c']

h = Hash[ 
  data.zip([0] * data.length)
]
p h

--output:--
{"a"=>0, "b"=>0, "c"=>0}
```

But perhaps you just want a Set:

```
require 'set'

data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
s = Set.new(data)

puts 'yes' if s.include?('b')  #=> yes
```

Comment: Perhaps add the proviso that this approach might be taken if it's part of a Rails app. If it's a pure Ruby app, loading `activesupport` would be driving a tack with a sledgehammer, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Rather than `data.zip([0] * data.length`, you could write `data.product([0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
require 'date'

# we're explicit so it's easier to see what our "magic values" are doing
MONDAY = 1

# today isn't valid so our starting point is yesterday
yesterday = Date.today - 1

# we find out how many days of adjustment we need
offset = (yesterday - MONDAY).wday % 7

# map the results over 52 weeks
h = Hash[(0..51).map{|week| [yesterday - (week * 7 + offset), 0]}]
```